# Magento 2: Custom Options - info between?

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options

Is there a way for me to place text between the custom options on my product page? I'd like to separate each option (size, message, text field) with some information relating to the option beneath each piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Editing the templates of Magento_Catalog module (module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/select.phtml etc.)
2. Or creating a module that will add this functionality to Magento2.

Comment: Any free extension for custom options

Answer (score 0):

You need to override below files to change in product custom option (base on your option type):

> \magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\options\type\select.phtml
>   \magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\options\type\date.phtml
>   \magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\options\type\file.phtml
>   \magento2\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\options\type\text.phtml

You can override this by two way:

```
1) Copy this file to your custom theme (with same file path).
2) Copy this file and catalog_product_view.xml to your new extension.
```